# Reading a text file in Python and choosing categories from it? Hotel

Tags: python

A hotel salesperson enters sales in a text file. Each line contains the following, separated by semicolons: The name of the client, the service sold (such as Dinner, Conference, Lodging, and so on), the amount of the sale, and the date of that event. Write a program that reads such a file and displays the total amount for each service category. Display an error if the

My text file contains

```
Bob;Dinner;10.00;January 1, 2015
Tom;Dinner;14.00;January 2, 2015
Anne;Lodging;125.00;January 3, 2015
Jerry;Lodging;125.00;January 4, 2015
```

so here is my code so far

```
def main():
    file_name = input("Input file name: ")
    amount_by_category = process_file(file_name)
    if amount_by_category:
        print 'Totals:'
        for key in amount_by_category:
            print '{0}: $ {1}'.format(key, amount_by_category.get(key) )

def process_file(file_name):
    infile = open(file_name, 'r')
    # a dictionary mapping category to total amount for that category
    amount_by_category = {}
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split(';')
        if len(fields) != 4:
            raise Exception('Expected 4 fields but found %s' % len(fields))
        value = float(fields[2])
        category = fields[1]
        if not category in amount_by_category:
            amount_by_category[category] = 0.0
        amount_by_category[category] += value
    return amount_by_category

main()
```

I'm getting a syntax error and not sure why.

And the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Assignment 7\girrrr.py", 
line 24, in <module> main() File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Assignment 7\girrrr.py", 
line 7, in main print ('{0}: $ {1}').format(key, amount_by_category.get(key) ) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: You should post the full error. It will include a line number.

Comment: could you add traceback with exception to your question?

Comment: it's a invalid syntax on print 'Totals:'

Comment: ok fixed the error listed above but i get this error now Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Assignment 7\girrrr.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Assignment 7\girrrr.py", line 7, in main
    print ('{0}: $ {1}').format(key, amount_by_category.get(key) )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: It's working in python 2.7 , this print statement will work for python 2.7. But you need to use raw_input instead of input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an old python, but this code works just fine in 3.6:

```
def main():
    file_name = input("Input file name: ")
    amount_by_category = process_file(file_name)
    if amount_by_category:
        print ("Totals:")
        for key in amount_by_category:
            print ("{}: $ {}".format(key, amount_by_category.get(key)))

def process_file(file_name):
    infile = open(file_name, 'r')
    # a dictionary mapping category to total amount for that category
    amount_by_category = {}
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split(';')
        if len(fields) != 4:
            raise Exception('Expected 4 fields but found %s' % len(fields))
        value = float(fields[2])
        category = fields[1]
        if not category in amount_by_category:
            amount_by_category[category] = 0.0
        amount_by_category[category] += value
    return amount_by_category

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The traceback you have shared looks like this:

```
print ('{0}: $ {1}').format(key, amount_by_category.get(key) )
```

while you code looks like this:

```
print '{0}: $ {1}'.format(key, amount_by_category.get(key) )
```

I tried running your code, It runs fine. Try re-running the code, It should work.